# Multiple Drag and Drop in dynatree

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynatree, jquery-dynatree

In **Dynatree**, Drag and drop functionality is enabled by defining the appropriate callbacks:

```
$("#tree").dynatree({
        [...]
        dnd: {
            onDragStart: function(node) {
                /** This function MUST be defined to enable dragging for the tree.
                 *  Return false to cancel dragging of node.
                 */
                logMsg("tree.onDragStart(%o)", node);
                return true;
            },
            onDrop: function(node, sourceNode, hitMode, ui, draggable) {
                /** This function MUST be defined to enable dropping of items on
                 * the tree.
                 */
                logMsg("tree.onDrop(%o, %o, %s)", node, sourceNode, hitMode);
                sourceNode.move(node, hitMode);
            }
        }
    });
```

but, *Is it possible to drag and drop more than one item at a time*? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would recommend to upgrade to Fancytree, that also contains an example http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/#sample-multi-dnd.html